# Travis for personal private repository

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am working on a private repo, I need to integrate CI for my app. How to integrate travis for my private repo. Or is it possible to have travis on our server

Comment: Checkout this article: [10 Hosted Continuous Integration Services for a Private Repository](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/10/05/ten-hosted-continuous-integration-services.html)

Answer (score 12):

[Travis Pro](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/travis-pro/) supports private github repos.

Comment: 63/mo billed annually :/

Answer (score 5):

There are other hosted CI services. For example, you could use [Circle](https://circleci.com).

Answer (score 1):

Also, if running Travis checks locally will be enough for your case, see: https://github.com/PaulRosset/previs